# How to set discount price for Grouped Product In Magento 2

Tags: magento2

For Example: I have two simple product Mobile Phone of Price: 500$ and 1 Memory Card of price 10$. Total is 510 $.

I want to sell both product as a group at Price 505$.

From Admin section i'm not able to see any price configuration for Group Product IN Magneto 2.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the price attribute is missing in your Attribute set.
Please check: Stores --> Attributes --> Attribute Set

Normally, you can choose **Advanced Pricing** for this

[image]

Comment: i have checked for price attribute , it is their in default attribute set, and i'm using that only attribute set. The price attribute not appearing only for group product.

Answer (score 0):

For Grouped Products the price is calculated as the sum of the prices of the  individual products. 
That's also why the price section is missing for grouped products.

Comment: @Davіd while this answer is really short, it really seems reasonable as a possible reason for missing price on product group.

Answer (score 0):

The grouped products in Magento mainly serve as a way to display few products on one page. You can't set a price for the grouped product since Magento calculates the price dynamically by summing up the children products' prices that were selected by the customer. That is if the customer adds the mobile phone and the memory card to cart from within the grouped product page, the price will be $500+$10 = $510.

Therefore, if you want to be able to set a different price for products that were purchased together, there are two options:

1) Use a Bundled Product (with Price Type = Fixed Price) and set the phone and the memory card as it's children. In this case, you can set the bundled product price to be $505.

There are few limitations to this solution:

- The customer can't just add the mobile phone or the memory card to cart separately from this page, he can only add them together. That is the customer will need to go to a separate page to purchase the mobile phone (or the memory card) standalone.
- Once the user added the bundled product to his cart, he can't just remove one child product from the cart (e.g the memory cart) - he has to remove both.

2) You can use an extension for it. One of the extensions that implement this functionality is [Bundled Discount](https://www.mexbs.com/bundled-discount-magento2-extension). It allows you to set the products of group A (in your case - the mobile phone) and the products of group B (in your case the memory card) and set the special price whenever they are purchased together (eg: $505).

It also allows you to create a separate page for the bundled promotion. This way, the user can select whether he wants to add only the mobile phone for $500, the memory card for $10, all both for $505.

The user can also remove one of the products from his cart and only pay for another product (eg: the user removes the memory card from his cart and only pays $500 for the phone).

**Disclaimer: I am the CEO of the company that developed the Bundled Discount extension.**